# asmx HTTP Post request with parameters

Tags: php, soap, http-post, asmx

our company has a .net base website
a few days ago we request a webservice from our website programmer  and yesterday he sent me a URL
when i open the URL from localhost its shown a page that i can choose one of my four method (function) that we request to programming.
by choosing one of them a new page has boon shown as follow:

SOAP 1.1
The following is a sample SOAP 1.1 request and response. The placeholders shown need to be replaced with actual values.

> POST /webservices/findstatus.asmx HTTP/1.1   Host: localhost
>   Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8   Content-Length: length
>   SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/FindWith_CodeR_Serail"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">  
  <soap:Body>  
    <FindWith_CodeR_Serail xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">  
      <CodeReception>int</CodeReception>  
      <Serial>string</Serial>  
    </FindWith_CodeR_Serail>  
  </soap:Body>  
</soap:Envelope>
```

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK   Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
>   Content-Length: length

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">  
  <soap:Body>  
    <FindWith_CodeR_SerailResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">  
      <FindWith_CodeR_SerailResult>string</FindWith_CodeR_SerailResult>  
    </FindWith_CodeR_SerailResponse>  
  </soap:Body>  
</soap:Envelope>
```

SOAP 1.2
The following is a sample SOAP 1.2 request and response. The placeholders shown need to be replaced with actual values.

> POST /webservices/findstatus.asmx HTTP/1.1   Host: localhost
>   Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8   Content-Length:
>   length

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">  
  <soap12:Body>  
    <FindWith_CodeR_Serail xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">  
      <CodeReception>int</CodeReception>  
      <Serial>string</Serial>  
    </FindWith_CodeR_Serail>  
  </soap12:Body>  
</soap12:Envelope>
```

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK   Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
>   Content-Length: length

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">  
  <soap12:Body>  
    <FindWith_CodeR_SerailResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">  
      <FindWith_CodeR_SerailResult>string</FindWith_CodeR_SerailResult>  
    </FindWith_CodeR_SerailResponse>  
  </soap12:Body>  
</soap12:Envelope>
```

HTTP POST
The following is a sample HTTP POST request and response. The placeholders shown need to be replaced with actual values.

> POST /webservices/findstatus.asmx/FindWith_CodeR_Serail HTTP/1.1
>   Host: localhost   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>   Content-Length: length      CodeReception=string&Serial=string
>   HTTP/1.1 200 OK   Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
>   Content-Length: length

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">string</string>
```

Now i'm stock on php codes that call this web service with 2 parameter
please send me full code that i can paste it in a php file for test.
no matter what kind of method is used : SOAP or HTTP POST

please help me.

i used this php code and every thing is OK:

```
<?php

$client = new SoapClient("http://www.MyWebSite.com/webservices/findstatus.asmx?WSDL");
$params=new stdClass();
$params->CodeReception = '11111';
$params->Serial = '22222222';    
$result = $client->FindWith_CodeR_Serail($params)->FindWith_CodeR_SerailResult;
echo  $result;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$client = new SoapClient("http://www.MyWebSite.com/webservices/findstatus.asmx?WSDL");
$params=new stdClass();
$params->CodeReception = '11111';
$params->Serial = '22222222';    
$result = $client->FindWith_CodeR_Serail($params)->FindWith_CodeR_SerailResult;
echo  $result;
?>
```